# Random deleting of rows

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

I need to chose *i* random rows of a `W_tot_migl` matrix. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
[m, n] = size(W_tot_migl); % m data points, n dimensions
randomPoints = [];
for i=1:14250
     index = random('unid', m); % Pick the index at random.
     randomPoints(i,:) = W_tot_migl(index,:); % Add random point.
     W_tot_migl(index,:) = []; % Delete selected row.
     m = m-1;
end
```

Is there a faster way, maybe avoiding the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more matlab way to do it:

```
nr = 5; %How many do you want to pick

n = size(W_tot_migl,1); 
idx = randperm(n,nr);

randomPoints = W_tot_migl(idx,:);
W_tot_migl(idx,:) = [];
```

Note that as you pick them all at once, you do not need to worry about duplicates. If that is the only reason for deleting them from the original the last line is now obsolete.

Comment: Note that for (not too) old versions of Matlab `randperm` only admits the first argument. In that case you can use: `idx = randperm(n); idx = idx(1:nr);`